# How we can make custom Step for ForEach SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a ForEach loop which works with index, how I can make this ForEach step get custom step, because in ForEach in every single loop, it will add one to index, how we cam make step be 5, it means in every single loop adds 5 instead 1. I can make it possible with if and %, but I do not want ForEach try every each Item inside Items. how we can make it efficient coding?

Code:

```
 struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        
        
        List
        {
            ForEach(0 ..< 21) { index in // (Step == 5) not 1
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()
            }
  
        }
 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
List
{
    ForEach(Array(stride(from: 0, to: 21, by: 5)), id: \.self) { index in // (Step == 5) not 1
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }

}
```

Comment: could we delete (id: \.self) or change the form of ForEach a little bit? I mean, I want index read the value of Array also, not just count of it.

Comment: *could we delete (id: \.self)* - no (ForEach is not an iterator expression it is view builder with special constructor contract). *I want index read* - index variable contains a value, ie: 0, 5, 10...

Comment: your code is perfect, I was Curious to delete (id: \.self), and make it same result with .indices, but it did not pan out, that start just counting items, not using the item value, that is why I asked you for that. but no problem, i am using (id: \.self), for me(id: \.self) it is ugly coding.